# Set of differential equations modeling biological system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im trying to describe a moleculatr biological system using some differntial equations,
However, differntial equations is not my strong side.

I'm thinking my equation set is quite trivial but i just cant seem to manage it.
for 3 distinct groups im trying to calculate $V_1(t)$, expressed by:

$V_1(t)=V_2'(t) \,k1$

$V_2(t)=V_1'(t) \,k_2+V_3'(t) \,k_3$

$V_3(t)=V_2'(t)\,k_4$

for $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ some constants.

every input will be really helpfull.
thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $v= k \, v'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing the functions a single column vector ${\bf v}_(t)=[v_1(t),v_2(t),v_3(t)]^T$ you can rewrite your system of three linear differential equations as a single matricial one:

$${\bf v} = {\bf A} \frac{d{\bf v}}{dt}$$

where $${\bf A}=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0     &  k_1 &0 \\ 
  k_2 & 0  & k_3\\
 0 & k_4 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, if you know to solve a first order linear diferential equation with constant coefficient, the procedure and the result is basically the same. [See eg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation). Can you go on from here?

Comment: thanks alot! this really helps!